# Can Obama pardon Clinton?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution

Pardons are mentioned in the United States Constitution at Article 2, Section 2.

> ... The President ... shall have Power to Grant Reprieves and Pardons for Offenses against the United States, except in Cases of Impeachment.

Can Obama legally pardon Clinton for any potential crimes she might be convicted of in the future? Would such a pardon likely withstand challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

For precedent see Gerald Ford's [pardon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardon_of_Richard_Nixon) of Richard Nixon.